# mapInfo in SCORM 2004 3rd Edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Please read the following scenario and tell me what's the problem:

1. I have two Content Packages (CP1 and CP2).
2. CP2 has objectivesGlobalToSystem = true.
3. CP2 has a global objective with readSatisfiedStatus = true and targetObjectiveID = g-obj.
4. CP1 has a local objective with writeSatisfiedStatus = true and targetObjectiveID = g-obj.
5. Objective Progress Status and Objective Satisfied Status of local objective of CP1 are true.
6. CP1 is launched and Objective Satisfied Status of the local objective is written to the global objective of CP2 after an Exit All Navigation Request.
7. The control returns to the LMS.
8. CP1 is launched again. What is the value of Objective Progress Status and Objective Satisfied Status of local objective of CP1?

Answer (score 1):

CP1 will not be affected because it doesn't read the global objective values. Only CP2 has access to the global objective values since it has "readSatisfiedStatus" set to true. "writeSatisfiedStatus" is the same as assigning a value to a variable, while "readSatisfiedStatus" reads the value assigned to that variable.

Comment: In the above scenario, the Tracking Model (i.e., Objective Progress Information, Activity Progress Information and Attempt Progress Information) of all activities in the Activity Tree are reinitialized to their default value because of an Exit All navigation request. For example Objective Progress Status and Objective Satisfied Status for the global objective (in CP1) are set to false because of an Exit All navigation request. Am I right?